# In Gnome, how do I backup my spell-check dictionary?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, gnome, spell-check, dictionary

I frequently add non-standard words to the dictionary, and would not like to lose it. Is there any way to save it somewhere, so that I would never have to start over ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found these dictionaries in my system with `locate`:

```
/home/user/.config/enchant/en_GB.dic
/home/user/.config/enchant/en_US.dic
/home/user/.config/enchant/hu_HU.dic
```

Generally $HOME/.config contains all types of configuration for your programs.

update:
  I found the corresponding specification I was looking for: [XDG Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-0.6.html).